# Error due to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I'm getting the following warning message on my web page:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

How I can resolve it?

I'm using the following scripts:

```
<script src="https://www.markettrendsignal.com/beta/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.markettrendsignal.com/beta/js/thickbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
<script src="https://www.markettrendsignal.com/beta/js/jquery.treeview.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.markettrendsignal.com/beta/js/jquery.tipTip.minified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.markettrendsignal.com/beta/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js'></script>
```

Comment: this is not enough information.  Put together a jsfiddle or something

Comment: Someone has an infinite loop!

Comment: this is the jquery library link, this cannot stop the page. Provide other parts of the code too, a fiddle or something.

Answer (score -1):

probably need to see more of the page.  you may have some kind of recursive javascript that is taking advantage of jQuery, so the root cause is not jQuery, but the other javascript that uses it...